# check and compare associative array value with in_array?

Tags: arrays, session, associative-array

I am trying to using the `in_array` function to check the value exists in the second array or not. I want to search 556729685 from the following array:

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] =

Array
( 
    [cart_item] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => Array 
                ( 
                    [product_name] => White Sakura Necktie
                    [id] => 11
                    [product_auto_id] => 556729685
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [product_regular_price] => 95
                    [product_sale_price] => 95
                    [product_image] => 556729680Black_Sakura_Necktie.jpg 
                )
            [1] => Array 
                ( 
                    [product_name] => hhhad ba bhdbh
                    [id] => 10
                    [product_auto_id] => 951790801
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [product_regular_price] => 20
                    [product_sale_price] => 
                    [product_image] => 951790801hhhad_ba_bhdbh_.jpg 
                )
        ) 
)
```

I am using following functions to check but it is giving wrong out put:

```
in_array(556729685, array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]));
```

I have tried this one also:

```
in_array(556729685, array_values($_SESSION["cart_item"]));
```

None is working so help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associative array consist of key, column and values. So, in order to check existence of value you need to reach key of array.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION["cart_item"]);$i++)
{
     if( in_array( 556729685 ,$_SESSION["cart_item"][$i] ) )
    {
      echo "exist in id:".$i.'<br/>';
    }
}
```